# How can I change the files in Ubuntu /snap folder?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea, snapcraft

I install IntelliJ IDEA from Ubuntu Software Center, I wanna change `${IDEA Folder}/bin/idea64.vmoptions` .

The full path is `/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/91/bin/idea64.vmoptions`

When I try to change this file, it returns "Read-only file system"

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544869. You should never change this file, edit a copy instead via Help | Edit Custom VM Options.

Answer (score 0):

During registration with a serveer I was getting `ticket obtaining prohibited`

Under linux/snap to register with the server:

I had to open the app and go for a free trail, then as @CrazyCoder said go for Help, Edit custom vm options and add `-Duser.name=myUserName` then restart and go for Help, Register and then set the license server...

Comment: Do you mean restart PyCharm or restart the computer ?